# Linux find files in all similar paths

Tags: wordpress, search, terminal

I have many Wordpress sites on a server. How can I use find command to e.g. find all .htaccess files in all root directories? Say I have a folder /var/www/html and in there I have all sites

```
/var/www/html/site1/html/
/var/www/html/site2/html/
/var/www/html/site3/html/
```

Now I would like to find all files in each sites "wp-content" catalog. And see if there is a text in each file.

Find all files ".htaccess" in all sites "wp-content" catalog, and check if the files contain the text "foobar-1"

I can check this is specific catalogs but want to find in all the folders with the same name in all sites

```
find . -name ".htaccess" | grep "foobar-1"
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood properly, and you only want to check in the `wp-content` directory itself (not subdirectories), and if all the site structures are the same, something like this should show all the names of all the `.htaccess` files that contain `foobar-1`:

```
grep -l "foobar-1" /var/www/html/*/html/wp-content/.htaccess
```

If you also need to check subdirectories, or if the site structures differ (eg sometimes you run WordPress out of a subdirectory) you're on the right track with `find`

```
find /var/www/html -name ".htaccess" -exec grep - "foobar-1" {} \;
```

Both of those are untested, but hopefully they'll point you in the right direction if I've made a typo.

Comment: Thanks. This did work! I also found out that to find only the `.htaccess` files directly under the `/var/www/html/*/html/` catalogs and **NOT** recursively (there were some in sub catalogs) - So I used the `-maxdepth` switch. Here is the command to find only ".htaccess" directly in my sites root: `find /var/www/html/*/html/ -maxdepth 1 -name ".htaccess"`